# Select where item contains all tags but does not have any unwanted tags

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a database set up where `media` items have many `tags`, whose relations are linked through a `media_tags` table. I want to be able to request media items that have certain tags, but that don't have certain other tags.

For example, let's say I wanted all items that had the tags 'vehicle' AND 'object', but not items that had the tags 'truck' OR 'van'. So if my data was:

```
id | name           | tags
1  | Honda Civic    | object,vehicle,car
2  | Bucket         | object
3  | Ford Transit   | object,vehicle,van
4  | Ford Econoline | object,vehicle,truck
5  | Golf Ball      | object
6  | Toyota Camry   | object,vehicle,car
```

I want the query to return the Honda Civic and the Toyota Camry, because they have the "object" and "vehicle" tags, but they don't have the "van" or "truck" tags.

I've figured out how to do the first part already:

```
SELECT * FROM media
INNER JOIN media_tags ON media_tags.media_id = media.id
INNER JOIN tags ON (tags.id=media_tags.tag_id)
WHERE (tags.name = 'object' OR tags.name = 'vehicle')
GROUP BY media.id
HAVING COUNT(distinct media_tags.tag_id) = 2;
```

But I can't figure out how to write a query that ignores media items that have either 'truck' or 'van' as tags.

Comment: please post some sample data and the expected result as the question is not totally clear.

Comment: is the data stored as shown?is `tags` a comma separated values column?

Comment: No, I simplified it for that part of the example. In reality, there would be an "media" table with at least an "id" column, a "tags" table with the columns "id" and "name", and a "media_tags" table with a "media_id" column and a "tag_id" column that links them both together. I can add this to the post if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add these lines to exclude rows with the extra tags:

```
SELECT * FROM media
INNER JOIN media_tags ON media_tags.media_id = media.id
INNER JOIN tags ON (tags.id=media_tags.tag_id)
WHERE (tags.name = 'object' OR tags.name = 'vehicle')
AND 0 = (
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM tags as T1
  WHERE T1.id = media_tags.tag_id
  AND tags.name IN ('van','truck')
)
GROUP BY media.id
HAVING COUNT(distinct media_tags.tag_id) = 2;
```